# MATE Authentication

Tags: mate

I am running `mate 1.8` on `armv7 pc linaro`. The pc is headless so I'm connecting to it with `tightvnc`.

I manually installed the `ubuntu-software-center` to try it out. Whenever I try to install something using the center, it says:

```
Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not
available.
(org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.44'}): 
org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages"
```

I have tried to run policy kit manually; it gives "(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:3743): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 3743'' The gnome-authentication-agent is set to run at start. `/etc/X11/default- display-manager` shows that lxdm is default. Synaptic doesn't work either; just doesn't open. Both work perfectly when ran with sudo in the Mate terminal. Any suggestions?